# How to extract sub strings from huge string in python?

Tags: python, parsing

I have huge strings (7-10k characters) from log files that I need to automatically extract and tabulate information from. Each string contains approximately 40 values that are input by various people. Example;

```
Example string 1.) 'Color=Blue, [randomJunkdataExampleHere] Weight=345Kg, Age=34 Years, error#1 randomJunkdataExampleThere error#1'
Example string 2.) '[randomJunkdataExampleHere]   Color=Red 42, Weight=256 Lbs., Age=34yers, error#1, error#2'
Example string 3.) 'Color=Yellow 13,Weight=345lbs., Age=56  [randomJunkdataExampleHere]'
```

Desired outcome is a new string, or even dictionary that organizes the data and readies for database entry (one string for each row of data);

```
Color,Weight,Age,Error#1Count,Error#2Count
blue,345,34,2,0
red,256,24,1,1
yellow,345,56,0,0
```

Considered using re.search for each column/value, but since there's variance in how users input data I don't know how to trap just the numbers that I want to extract. Also have no idea how to capture the number of times a 'Error#1Count' occurs in the string.

```
import re
line = '[randomJunkdataExampleHere] Color=Blue, Weight=345Kg, Age=34 Years, error#1, randomJunkdataExampleThere error#1'

try:    
    Weight = re.search('Weight=(.+?), Age',line).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    Weight = 'ERROR'
```

Goal/Result:

```
Color,Weight,Age,Error#1Count,Error#2Count
blue,345,34,2,0
red,256,24,1,1
yellow,345,56,0,0
```

Comment: 10,000 characters is nothing (only 10kb assuming ASCII encoding). Have you tried a naieve approach ?

Comment: Based on those examples, splitting the string on commas seems like a really good start.

Comment: parsing data depends on knowing what you can and can't rely on which ultimately depends on how the strings are being created. For example your strings suggests the data is Field=Value (with Value possibly including units) with no spaces and Field, Value pairs are always comma separated. Is this true?

Comment: This post has like 4 questions

Comment: @ eddiewould: I don't know what naieve approach is. @ John Gordon: I made a mistake with the original example. The log file files contain random information and can't be delimited by repeating characters. @ Andrew Allen: Apologies for the original bad examples. The log files are very messy, and generated by various versions of software that do not log data consistently (example: Color, Colour, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, 10000 characters really isn't a huge deal.

```
import time

example_string_1 = 'Color=Blue, Weight=345Kg, Age=34 Years, error#1, error#1'
example_string_2 = 'Color=Red 42, Weight=256 Lbs., Age=34 yers, error#1, error#2'
example_string_3 = 'Color=Yellow 13, Weight=345lbs., Age=56'

def run():
examples = [example_string_1, example_string_2, example_string_3]
dict_list = []

for example in examples:
    # first, I would suggest tokenizing the string to identify individual data entries.
    tokens = example.split(', ')
    my_dict = {}
    for token in tokens: # Non-error case
        if '=' in token:
            subtokens = token.split('=') # this will split the token into two parts, i.e ['Color', 'Blue']
            my_dict[subtokens[0]] = subtokens[1]
        elif '#' in token: # error case. Not sure if this is actually the format. If not, you'll have to find something to key off of.
            if 'error' not in my_dict or my_dict['error'] is None:
                my_dict['error'] = [token]
            else:
                my_dict['error'].append(token)
    dict_list.append(my_dict)

# Now lets test out how fast it is.
before = time.time()

for i in range(100000): # run it a hundred thousand times
    run()

after = time.time()

print("Time: {0}".format(after - before))
```

Yields:

```
Time: 0.5782015323638916
```

See? Not too bad. Now all that is left is to iterate over the dictionary and record the metrics you want.